# Mongodb (using mongoose) expiresAfterSeconds (TTL) doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose for this.

My Schema is like this:

```
var UsuarioSchema = new Schema({
    email : { type : Email, index : { unique : true}, required : true },
    //some other fields, but not required, hopefully, for this sample code
    test_expira : { type : Date, default : Date.now, index : { expires : 120 }}
});
```

When running on the mongodb shell, this is the information that I believe matters:

```
> db.usuarios.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "dbnamehere.usuarios",
        "name" : "_id_"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "email" : 1
        },
        "unique" : true,
        "ns" : "dbnamehere.usuarios",
        "name" : "email_1",
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : true
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "test_expira" : 1
        },
        "ns" : "dbnamehere.usuarios",
        "name" : "test_expira_1",
        "expiresAfterSeconds" : 120,
        "background" : true,
        "safe" : true
    }
]
> new Date();
ISODate("2013-06-12T17:41:43.263Z")
> db.usuarios.findOne({email : 'someemail@gmail.com'});
{
    /* some fields go in here! */
    "email" : "someemail@gmail.com",
    /* some more fields go in here */
    "_id" : ObjectId("51b8b087de01a2ec28000002"),
    "test_expira" : ISODate("2013-06-12T17:31:51.156Z"),
    /* some yet more fields go in here */
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I haven't tested for how long it goes without getting deleted, but even the docs state only a minute overhead should be what one could expect, but not over 15 minutes for a document that should last only 120 seconds.

I'm unsure of how to deal with this. Help will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:
Version of mongodb being used is v2.4.4
Version of mongoose is 3.0.3

Comment: look in mongod log - do you see TTLMonitor thread running every minute?

Comment: btw, while you are in the logs, make note of what time it is on the server - new Date() gives you shell host time, not server time. It might be earlier on your server.

Comment: I found no evidence of TTLMonitor running. I am unsure of where in the mongodb.conf I should specify this configuration, in case I have to explicitly indicate it is required, I know my current conf file does not indicate it... I thought that just by adding the index the TTLMonitor thread would automatically start running. Also, thank you for your response!

Comment: BTW, checked the time. It seems like mongodb server and webserver timezones are not matching (this is a dev vm, so there wasn't that much detail on the configuration). Even then, the timezone difference is not big enough to justify that the record still hasn't been deleted after 9 hours (the timezone difference seems to be of exactly 5 hours). But I do believe that the time difference is ignored due to the ISODate being on greenwich always, and it just adjusts the datetime to whatever timezone the server is. Am I right on this?

Comment: you are correct about timezone not being an issue - but sometimes servers (especially dev vms) can be brought up in the wrong day or year which can cause all kinds of confusion. ruling that out can save time. how about the server log - does it show TTLMonitor thread running?  What configuration is this - a stand-alone mongod or a replica set?

Comment: so TTLMonitor thread should always run EXCEPT if this server (mongod) was configured as a member of a replica set but then started up without --replSet option.  Try this command in mongo shell: db.adminCommand('getCmdLineOpts')

Comment: I read about how it works with replicas. This is just stand alone. Here's the output of the command you suggested: http://pastebin.com/pJssTAeJ

Comment: my bad - TTLMonitor doesn't log to the mongod log at default logLevel.  You can temporarily up your logging and see what it's doing by typing this at the mongo shell:  db.adminCommand({setParameter:1, logLevel:1})   (after a few minutes you can set it back by changing logLevel:1 to logLevel:0).  It will show TTLMonitor thread looking for things to delete and whether it finds anything.  If you paste that into here or pastebin it should show what's happening.  I'm just testing it myself. Okay, test complete - it works fine for me...

Comment: found it! see my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tested this feature and it works fine with 2.4.4 MongoDB.

Having taken a closer look at your indexes I realized the problem is a small typo.

My TTL index which works:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "test_expira" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "test.usuarios",
    "name" : "test_expira_1",
    "expireAfterSeconds" : 120,
    "background" : true,
    "safe" : true
}
```

Your TTL index which does not work:

```
{
    "v" : 1,
    "key" : {
        "test_expira" : 1
    },
    "ns" : "dbnamehere.usuarios",
    "name" : "test_expira_1",
    "expiresAfterSeconds" : 120,
    "background" : true,
    "safe" : true
}
```

Note the correct keyname for TTL index is "expireAfterSeconds" where yours has an extra letter and is "expiresAfterSeconds".

Comment: I realize that you are using mongoose and "expires" is the proper way to specify this property in its syntax.  I'm checking to see where the disconnect is between Mongooose and MongoDB index definition.

Comment: Looks like this bug in Mongoose was fixed 9 months ago - update your mongoose version?   https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1132

Comment: The fix is present in every mongoose version from 3.2.2 till current.  3.0.3 which you are using was the first version that added support for TTL indexes so 3.0.3 through 3.2.1 had this problem.

Comment: Got it. Awesome :) It actually got fixed last night because I upgraded all code to run with newer versions of modules (I hadn't done upgrades for express 2.11 to 3.X, and others, because of compatibility with older code.